# A list and a dataframe mapping to get a column value in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have a dataframe with words as index and a corresponding sentiment score in another column. Then, I have another dataframe which has one column with list of words (token list) with multiple rows. So each row will have a column with different lists. I want to find the average of sentiment score for a particular list. This has to be done for a huge number of rows, and hence efficiency is important.
One method I have in mind is given below:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['hi', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'sample']]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['tokens'] = a

'''
df
                       words
0                  [a, b, c]
1  [hi, this, is, a, sample]
'''

def find_score(tokenlist, ref_df):
    # ref_df contains two cols, 'tokens' and 'score'
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
    temp_df['tokens'] = tokenlist
    return temp_df.merge(ref_df, on='tokens', how='inner')['sentiment_score'].mean(axis=0) 
    # this should return score

df['score'] = df['tokens'].apply(find_score, axis=1, args=(ref_df))
# each input for find_score will be a list
```

Is there any more efficient way to do it without creating dataframe for each list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary for mapping from the reference dataframe `ref_df` and then use [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) on each token list on each row of dataframe `df`, as follows:

```
ref_dict = dict(zip(ref_df['tokens'], ref_df['sentiment_score']))
df['score'] = df['tokens'].map(lambda x: np.mean([ref_dict[y] for y in x if y in ref_dict.keys()]))
```

### Demo

**Test Data Construction**

```
a = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['hi', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'sample']]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['tokens'] = a

ref_df = pd.DataFrame({'tokens': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'hi', 'this', 'is', 'sample', 'example'], 
'sentiment_score': [1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]})

print(df)

                      tokens
0                  [a, b, c]
1  [hi, this, is, a, sample]


print(ref_df)

    tokens  sentiment_score
0        a                1
1        b                2
2        c                3
3        d                4
4       hi               11
5     this               12
6       is               13
7   sample               14
8  example               15
```

**Run New Code**

```
ref_dict = dict(zip(ref_df['tokens'], ref_df['sentiment_score']))
df['score'] = df['tokens'].map(lambda x: np.mean([ref_dict[y] for y in x if y in ref_dict.keys()]))
```

**Output**

```
print(df)

                      tokens  score
0                  [a, b, c]    2.0
1  [hi, this, is, a, sample]   10.2
```

Comment: ref_df is comparatively larger. That shouldn't be an issue right? I'll try out both methods and try to add time taken by both here.

Comment: @Jihjohn  dict(zip()) is relatively fast. So shouldn't be an issue.  I have slightly fine-tuned the code to support the case when there is any word in df not found in ref_df.  In case your use case could have this situation, you can use the latest slightly enhanced code above.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode), [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge), and [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-seriesgroupby-aggregate):

```py
import pandas as pd

a = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['hi', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'sample']]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['tokens'] = a

ref_df = pd.DataFrame({'sentiment_score': {'a': 1, 'b': 2,
                                           'c': 3, 'hi': 4,
                                           'this': 5, 'is': 6,
                                           'sample': 7}})

# Explode Tokens into rows (Preserve original index)
new_df = df.explode('tokens').reset_index()
# Merge sentiment_scores
new_df = new_df.merge(ref_df, left_on='tokens',
                      right_index=True,
                      how='inner')
# Group By Original Index and agg back to lists and take mean
new_df = new_df.groupby('index') \
    .agg({'tokens': list, 'sentiment_score': 'mean'}) \
    .reset_index(drop=True)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
                      tokens  sentiment_score
0                  [a, b, c]              2.0
1  [a, hi, this, is, sample]              4.6
```

---

After Explode:

```
   index  tokens
0      0       a
1      0       b
2      0       c
3      1      hi
4      1    this
5      1      is
6      1       a
7      1  sample
```

After Merge

```
   index  tokens  sentiment_score
0      0       a                1
1      1       a                1
2      0       b                2
3      0       c                3
4      1      hi                4
5      1    this                5
6      1      is                6
7      1  sample                7
```

---

(The one-liner)

```py
new_df = df.explode('tokens') \
    .reset_index() \
    .merge(ref_df, left_on='tokens',
           right_index=True,
           how='inner') \
    .groupby('index') \
    .agg({'tokens': list, 'sentiment_score': 'mean'}) \
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

If the order of the tokens in the list matters, the scores can be calculated and merged back to the original df instead of using list aggregation:

```py
mean_scores = df.explode('tokens') \
    .reset_index() \
    .merge(ref_df, left_on='tokens',
           right_index=True,
           how='inner') \
    .groupby('index').mean() \
    .reset_index(drop=True)

new_df = df.merge(mean_scores,
                  left_index=True,
                  right_index=True)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
                      tokens  sentiment_score
0                  [a, b, c]              2.0
1  [hi, this, is, a, sample]              4.6
```